# Javascript UTC time zone is always negative

Tags: javascript, timezone

I use this code to get utc offset in hours:

```
new Date().getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
```

But it always returns me `-2` even thou my timezone is actualy `+1` why is that happening?

**EDIT** if i change my computer time zone to `UTC +2` it returns `-3`, really strange..

Comment: Does your browser know of your "*actual timezone*"?

Comment: @bergi well i don't know, how can i check that?

Comment: `Date.getTimezoneOffset()` means [offset from UTC to your locale](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset). Also, are your system in daylight-saving-time right now?

Comment: @Linas So I guess your system believes that your daylight-saving-time would be localtime + 1 hour ?

Comment: What is the name of your time zone?  What country are you in?

Comment: Then your timezone is actually CEST which is GMT+2, and -2 is the correct value from `getTimezoneOffset()`. All is correct. :-)  http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=239

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the expected behavior. `Date.getTimezoneOffset()` returns the offset *from UTC to your locale*, hence the negative to the number you expect.

The reason why a **+2** locale would return **-3**, is possible because of daylight saving effects, perhaps.

Comment: wow i have never though that Madara would be programmer, you just made my day lol

Comment: @Linas: I don't program. I look at the computer and it programs itself out of fear.

Comment: well it should after all your're Madara lol